# Can an immigration law firm in Bulgaria sue me in the US?

Tags: united-states, international, european-union, immigration

Two months ago I started to conduct an investment-based immigration program to Bulgaria with the aid of a Bulgarian law firm. After two months, I found they were extremely unprofessional (the bilingual documents provided had typos, many duplicated articles, even Google Translate results) and there were also hidden fees after I enrolled. I tried to negotiate with them for refund, which did not work. I started to question them for fraud and noticed them that I would ask for chargeback from my bank.

Then they sent me a quite threatening email, which included notify the embassy, file criminal complaint in Bulgaria, and some stuff about bilateral agreement between US and Bulgaria for lawsuit.

Some facts:
1. We did not sign any contract for the immigration service. I only provided them the scan copy of a lot personal documents. (Passport, no crime certificate, etc.)
2. The total number I asked for chargeback via my bank was around USD 11,000.
3. Currently I lived in the United States, but not a US citizen or PR.

Can they take legal action against me? By what method? In future, when I travel to EU (or even do another immigration program), will I get into any trouble if they really sue me in Bulgaria? I'd like to ask for advice for this situation.

Comment: Did you get your US visa with their help?

Comment: No, I obtained my US visa several years ago.

Answer (score 3):

You do have a contract - you agreed to pay them for services, that creates a contract.

If they have failed to provide the service that you paid for, the onus is on you to prove that. Getting a bank to make a chargeback when services have been provided in return for the payment is likely unlawful notwithstanding that you are not satisfied with the service they provided.

They can sue you in either Bulgaria or the USA and a judgement in one countries court will likely be enforceable in the other.

In addition, if you have committed a crime in Bulgaria then the Bulgarian police may investigate and may issue a warrant for your arrest and seek your extradition from wherever you happen to be.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's hard to say they provided any actual services. I decided to quit after seeing the poor-quality power of attorney they made. I even want to take legal action on them for the time loss, but the first thing is to secure my money. If they try to sue me, what actions can I take from my end?

Comment: @WilliamBrown Looks to me like they did provide actual services, although of low quality.  They may well not have done anything you actually find useful, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: @DavidThornley perhaps implied warrantees are pertinent here.